# Singly Linked List - Put last node after first node

Tags: java, data-structures, singly-linked-list

Let's say that I've a list that goes by 1->2->3->4->5. I want to put the last node after the first one so it goes like 1->5->2->3->4. This is my code but it doesn't work

```
public void Manipulate(){
        Node curr = head;
        Node next = null;
        Node last = head;

        while(last.next != null){
            last = last.next;
        }

        next = curr.next;
        last.next = next;
        curr.next = next.next;

    }


 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        SinglyLinkedList lista = new SinglyLinkedList();

        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        lista.addFirst(a);
        lista.insertAfter(a, b);

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
            int c = b;
            b = sc.nextInt();
            lista.insertAfter(c, b);
        }

        lista.addLast(34);
        lista.addLast(55);
        lista.addLast("Ginger");

        lista.Manipulate();
        System.out.println(lista);

    }
```

Comment: *what* does not work?

Comment: throws up an exception - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: and how is the manipulate method called?

Comment: provided my main method, you can check it out from there

Comment: How are we supposed to know what happens in `addFirst()`, `insertAfter()` etc. if you're not providing the code for that? Did you debug your code and check what happens? An OutOfMemoryError implies you're adding elements in some endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Manipulate() {
    Node penultimate = null;
    Node last = head;

    while(last.next != null){
        penultimate = last;
        last = last.next;
    }
    if (penultimate != null){ // closes the list
        penultimate.next = null;
    }
    if (last != head) { // move last element to second place
        last.next = head.next;
        head.next = last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post so it is more than just code. Why does this solve the OP's problem?

Comment: everLast.next = null; closes the list so there can't have any OP anymore when browsing the list.

Comment: Tx for the -1. For working code.
The guys gives incomplete bad code. I correct the error I can see. And I have to explain ??? He should look at my code and try to understand his mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You already got some improvement suggestions, so here's a little explaination what you actually did wrong.

The result of your code (as is) would be:

> 1->3->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->4->5->2->3->... (going on forever)

Which is why you run out of memory when trying to print that infinite beast.

First mistake: You need to actually make sure the element that will be the new last element does no longer have your former last element as `next`.

Second mistake: Your head element should have the former last element as `next`, not the `next` elements of its former `next` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Edge case: list has zero or 1 node:
    if(head == null || head.next == null) {
       return;
    }        
    Node prev = null;
    Node last = head;

    while(last.next != null){
        prev = last;
        last = last.next;
    }

    Node tmp = head.next;
    head.next = last;
    last.next = tmp;

    // Prevent loop by setting the next of the new last to null
    prev.next = null;
```